# Including css and js files on node.js + express + ejs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to use stylesheets and javascript files on my node.js project which uses express and ejs.

my structure:

```
public/
  -- css/
  -- js/
  -- images/
```

and my chat.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>
<body>

.. content ..

    <% include ../partials/footer %>

</body>
</html>
```

and in my partials/head.ejs there is code

```
<link href="public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it should load style file but it doesn't. Btw my main chat.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/chat');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

so how to use it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `public` folder won't actually be part of the URL paths available to the client:

```
<link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The path you give to `express.static()` will be combined with the URL path to the effect of:

```
// GET /css/custom.css
(__dirname + '/public') + '/css/custom.css'
```

---

So, when requesting `public/css/custom.css`, `express.static()` will try to find:

```
// GET /public/css/custom.css
(__dirname + '/public') + '/public/css/custom.css'
```

Expecting the folder structure to instead be:

```
public/
  -- public/
      -- css/
      -- js/
      -- images/
```